# Intermittent connectivity issue with Windows containers in EKS

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster running with both Linux and Windows nodes. On the Windows nodes i am scheduling pods. They run for about 30 minutes and then get removed. The first thing any pod does is download some data from S3 using the AWS cli installed on it.

I am facing some intermittent connectivity issues. Pods get spun up on and sometimes give a fatal error:

Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://sts.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

As far as i can see this only happens when I schedule more then one pod on a node. I do use a smaller instance type (M5.large) but i am not close to reaching the pod limit of this instance type. When there is 1 pod per node they can all connect and download data from S3.

Reading the documentation I can see it is possible to schedule more then 1 pod per EC2 instance. But I am unsure what the requirements are to the EC2 instance to give all those pods access to download data from S3. I did try to add more ENIs to the EC2 instances but this prevented the EC2 instances to be registered as nodes in the EKS cluster.

Comment: I have been able to get more then 1 pod on a node running. The intermittent issue of no connectivity remains. When I let the pod restart on error, on one of the restarts it usually gets a connection.

Comment: I have added a wait command before copying data from S3 into the pod. Apparantly the network connection was sometimes not fully initialized somewhere in the infrastructure.

Comment: @TatendaZifudzi Before executing my compute job on the pod I had to add a 60 seconds wait time to ensure internet connectivity to a pod. Without it sometimes it was there, sometimes not.

It is a workaround, not really a solution, but it worked. Currently I am not using Windows containers in EKS.

Comment: This is unexpected. If this behaviour is only happpening for Windows nodes, and you have clear steps to reproduce, please consider reaching out to AWS support with steps to reduce so you issue can be investigated. 

In your original question I see you attempted to add more ENIs to your Windows nodes. Multi ENI support is not yet available for Windows nodes.